# "échantillon" vs "échatillon"

Tags: sens, orthographe

I've seen both "échantillon" and "échatillon" in various places. They both seem to mean the same thing (e.g. 'sample'), so are these just two alternate spellings for the same word, or is one incorrect?

Comment: An *échatillon* is just an incomplete *échantillon*, pretty similar to a "saple" in English ;-)

Comment: @jiliagre So, a sample sample, if you like.

Answer (score 10):

[échatillon](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9chatillon) is clearly a typo, only [échantillon](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%A9chantillon) is valid.

Answer (score 1):

It must be an error. In statistics, for example, only the term "échantillon" is used. "Échatillon" is not in the dictionaries.